# Geocoding with rails search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation

I've been running into some location based searches using the Google Maps API (more of a structural issue on my end than any criticism of the mapping api)

For example, if a user searches for "Victoria, Canada" it will bring up results for "Victoria, Canada" as expected. However, if a user searches for "Canada," google returns a longitude and latitude for the middle of the country, which is essential for correctly centering the map. However, it will not display any results since the nearest location is too far away from the location returned by google. I'm filtering out results that are about 20 miles away.

Can the Google Maps API return anything that I could use to tell if a user has entered a state or country name? If not, has anyone developed a work around solution?

Ideally, I would like to avoid just ordering the results by nearest location. I don't want items for "Spain" showing up at the bottom of a list when a user searches for "United States." I would try to determine if the query is a state or country prior to the search, but this seems very daunting task given the different possible spelling of country and region names. If I was only expecting english spellings, it would be a much easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a form on a site that has a controller parse the form and send the request to Google's API, you could break the form out into address, city, state, and country (if needed) form elements then make the address and city required fields.

I'm doing a similar approach with a site I'm building using Google Places API and it seems to work for me.